# Reflections returning 0 even though class clearly exists

Tags: java, reflections

I have a problem with reflections. I have a class that extends another class called ClassModel:

```
package net.gd.globalwars.commands;

public class Country extends CommandModel { }
```

And as you can see it is in package "net.gd.globalwars.commands"
Now I am using a new reflection object to find all classes that extend CommandModel and print the count, but the count is 0.

```
Reflections commands = new Reflections("net.gd.globalwars.commands");
System.err.println(commands.getSubTypesOf(CommandModel.class).size());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using this maven dependency, the code works as it should and returns `1`:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
     <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Assuming:** `Country`, `CommandModel`, and the calling class are in the same package, though I doubt this makes a difference

Comment: Does it matter if the class is taken from a maven dependency?

Comment: It doesn't, just an easy way to communicate what version of the dependency I tried your code with.